# How to install application developed on emulator on Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android

I have developed a simple application on Emulator and would like to test/install it on Samsung Galaxy Tab. Could anybody let me know how to go about it?

Comment: What problems are you running into? In my experience, the process to install to a Samsung Galaxy Tab is no different from any other Android device (including phones). So all of the documentation you find online about deployment should apply equally well.

Comment: @ Chris: I am new to stackoverflow, was unaware that I have to check it to accept the answer, I always Thanked to all those who answered my questions. Anyways, Now I got to know about checking it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, plug the USB cable into your computer and use `adb` to install the package.  If the apk is named `MyApp.apk` and stored in the current working directory, you simply need to execute

```
adb install MyApp.apk
```

Make sure that you have checked `Allow Unknown Sources` in `Settings`.

Comment: I don't think you even need that setting checked when installing through ADB, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @schwiz, You very well could be right, I couldn't quite remember so I figured I'd suggest it :-).  I know it can't hurt

Comment: I think Chris meant to say "enable USB debugging" on the phone. In any case, this may not be enough. The last time I tried installing an app on a Galaxy Tab from a Windows PC, which granted was quite a while ago, I also needed to install some special driver from Samsung. So go to the Samsung web site and download that driver from their support section (this is in addition to the drivers found on the developer.android.com web site).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse on windows, ctrl+f11 (or f11 if you want to debug...) will compile and run your project. If you plug in your Galaxy Tab using a USB-microUSB cable, it should get priority over the emulators you've set up and automatically upload. Make sure USB debugging is enabled if you want to do any debugging.